# PHP CLI on Apple M1 using Homebrew

Tags: php, macos

I've followed [this guide](https://soffes.blog/homebrew-on-apple-silicon) to install Homebrew on an M1 based Mac.

After that I ran

```
brew install php@7.4
```

which installed PHP successfully.

If I now run

```
brew upgrade php
```

I get

```
Error: php not installed
```

What I like to achieve is to update the PHP that comes shipped with macOS, which is `7.3.22` when I run `php -v`.

How can I update PHP using Homebrew? I understood that I need to put something in my `PATH` to point to the newer PHP version? Given this is a new machine I actually don't have a `.bash_profile` file, only a `.zshrc` (I'm using ZSH, I assume that this file will be used and that I don't need a `.bash_profile`?)

Comment: I just had to do `brew link php` to override the built-in PHP. You should not be actually updating the built-in version.

Comment: Hooray! That fixed it. The only thing is that I needed to run it a little differently (because I installed a specific version of php probably?): `brew link php@7.4`. Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad that helped, done! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not advisable to upgrade the system-provided PHP, but it's also not necessary.

`brew link` can be used to decide *which* PHP is utilized. `brew link php@7.4` should do the trick; this can be also used to switch PHP versions around, i.e. `brew link php@8.0` will switch you over to that while leaving both versions installed and available directly.

Comment: I did `brew link php@8.0` and it says `Linking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php/8.0.2... 24 symlinks created`. But after that when I check the PHP version by `php -v`, it is still showing `PHP 7.3.24` version. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @AungSiMinHtet Run `which php` and make sure Brew's PHP is in your path. See https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are for more details.

Comment: I solved the problem by following this link https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php. Thanks for your help by the way.